# Get a VBScript to run properly while my computer is locked

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I put a `pause` into the code to break it down and make sure it is doing what it is supposed to do. Its not.

The `Check1.msl` will spit out a file named `check.rpt`. When I run it manually and the batch file pauses - `check.rpt` is there.  I schedule the task and lock my computer. When I log back in, the msl program is open and the cmd prompt is sitting at pause but there is NO `check.rpt` file.

Here is what I have at the beginning:

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "%~dp0"

ECHO CD is now %CD%

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 2000 -n 1
echo starting the check1 msl file
DIR Check1.msl
Start Check1.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 2000 -n 1
echo starting the password injector file
WScript //B passwordinjector.vbs

pause
POPD
exit
```

Here is the VBScript called `passwordinjector.vbs`

```
set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wshshell.AppActivate "User Login"
WshShell.SendKeys "Username"
WshShell.SendKeys "{tab}Password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{tab}{enter}"
```

I've tried `cscript passwordinjector.vbs` to no avail.

**EDIT:**

Researching (and common sense) I figured out that you can't `.SendKeys` while the computer is locked.  I need an alternative way to pass the log in information to the program.  How do I pass a username and password to a prompt from a program?

Comment: This is three questions in two days about the same batch file/vbscript. If you've worked out solutions to the other two (which it seems you have), you should post an answer to them so that they're not just hanging around, and so the answer can help other people. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you haven't solved those problems, and you're now just adding more detail, edit those questions instead and add it there.

Comment: I didn't say you offended me (or anyone else). I was simply suggesting that if you had solutions to the other issues, you should share them.

Comment: I dont have the other question answered.  They are related, though. I will work on being more concise.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I don't know what this msl file is you use but can the password not be specified within somehow? If not, as you found out yourself this is basically not possible with vbscript. If you really need such functionality autoit (and probably autohotkey) can send keys to programs even if they are not activated which means also when the computer is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can pass login information to a program depends on how that particular program expects login information. Unless you're able to present credentials in a commandline or something similar (like a HTTP POST request for instance) this can't be done with VBScript I'm afraid.

You may want to consider switching to something that is more suitable for GUI automation, like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: Thank you for your time explaining why it wouldn't be possible.